How to SKIP the header of a TSV file while creating an External Table in Red Shift?
I am trying to create an External Table from files stored in S3 location using Spectrum. The DDL is provided below,
create external table spectrum_intake.my_table_abcd (
    a varchar(50),
    b varchar(10),
    c varchar(10),
    d varchar(300)
)
row format delimited
    fields terminated by '\t'
    lines terminated by '\n\l'
stored as textfile
location 's3://my-bucket/input-files/'
table properties ('numRows'='100', 'skip.header.line.count'='1');


Not sure why I am still getting the 'File Headers' in my data.
Appreciate your help!!

I was using DataGrip and therefore the issue. When I executed the same through 'SQL Workbench' it worked.
